# How to score a portfolio's diversity based on security returns?

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, covariance

What is the best way to score a portfolio's diversity based on it's returns covariance matrix?

I know that if my portfolio has two securities and their returns' correlation coefficient is -1 that is a good diversified portfolio. Now I would like to know how do I score a portfolio with more than 2 securities.

If the theory is valid, should I calculate the correlation coefficient of N variables ? What's the formula for that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by diversity, but there's a (rather, at least one) question on average correlation. http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8689/average-correlation-of-index-portfolio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several measures discussed in the literature, the classical approach is [Markowitz mean-variance portfolio optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory).

The formula for portfolio return variance is
$$\sigma_p^2 = \sum_i w_i^2 \sigma_{i}^2 + \sum_i \sum_{j \neq i} w_i w_j \sigma_i \sigma_j \rho_{ij}$$
where $\rho_{ij}$ are the correlations betweent the assets.

Others suggeste measures are:

- **Normalized portfolio variance (NV)**, which is obtained by dividing the portfolio variance
  by the average variance of stock returns in the portfolio:
  $$ NV = \frac{\sigma^2_p}{\bar{\sigma}^2}$$
- **Sum of squared portfolio weights (SSPW)**, where $w_i$ is the portfolio weight assigned to stock $i$ in the portfolio and w_m is the portfolio weight assigned by the market (i.e. an index): 
  $$\sum_N (w_i-w_m)^2 $$

For more references, see for example:
Goetzmann and Kumar, [Equity portfolio diversification](ftp://economia.unica.it/mattana/Modelli_Mercati_Finanziari/Slides/Lecture_2/CRAA.pdf), Review of Finance, 2008
Google will give you a lot of results, I found this [Minimum Correlation Algorithm](http://cssanalytics.wordpress.com/2011/08/09/forecast-free-algorithms-a-new-benchmark-for-tactical-strategies/) interesting.